# HLSL function is not being recognized? undeclared error

Tags: c, xna, hlsl

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 TexCoord: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
float4 color1 = tex2D(inputSampler, TexCoord);
float numb = TestFunc( 5 );
float4 color3 = color1 + numb;
return color3;
}

float TestFunc(float numb)
{

return numb + 1;
}
```

I get an error saying error x3004: undeclared identifier 'TestFunc'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either declare `TestFunc()` before using it in PixelShaderFunction, or move it entirely before that. I. e.:

```
float TestFunc(float);

float PixelShaderFunction()
{
    // ...
}

float TestFunc(float n)
{
    // ...
}
```

or

```
float TestFunc(float n)
{
     // ...
}

float PixelShaderFunction()
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try declaring `TestFunc` before `PixelShaderFunction`, or forward declare it if it's allowed in HLSL:

```
float TestFunc(float numb);
```